# Injecting $compile into directive undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, angular-directive

I'm trying to inject $compile into my directive, so I can compile a directive before appending it to a div. Right now, $compile is undefined, am I injecting it wrong? I'm using ES6/Angular 1.5.x

```
    import MyController from './mycontroller';

    class MyDirective {
       constructor($compile) {
        this.restrict = 'A';
        this.scope = {};

        this.controller = MyController;
        this.controllerAs = 'vm';
        this._$compile = $compile;
     }

     link(scope, element) {
        let div = angular.element(document.getElementById('targetDiv'));

        // $compile is undefined
        let compiled = this._$compile("<another-directive></another-directive>")(scope));
     }

      static directiveFactory($compile){
        MyDirective.instance = new MyDirective($compile);
        return MyDirective.instance;
      }
    }

    MyDirective.directiveFactory.$inject = ['$compile'];

    export default MyDirective.directiveFactory;
```

Comment: I believe you must inject it into MyDirective rather than to directiveFactory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced similar issue with ES6 style, after lot of struggle, I figured out the below working pattern. Hope this solves your problem too. I

`this` inside link function of directive using ES6 style will be null. To have dependents injected and working in directive with ES6 style, please follow below style:

```
import MyController from './mycontroller';

class MyDirective {
   constructor() {
    this.restrict = 'A';
    this.scope = {};

    this.controller = MyController;
    this.controllerAs = 'vm';
 }

 link(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
    let div = angular.element(document.getElementById('targetDiv'));

    let compiled = ctrl.$compile("<another-directive></another-directive>")(scope));
 }

  static directiveFactory(){
    MyDirective.instance = new MyDirective();
    return MyDirective.instance;
  }
}

export default MyDirective.directiveFactory;
```

And in `mycontroller.js`, inject $compile service and bind it to controller's instance inside constructor. Below is the sample snippet:

```
export default class MyController {
   constructor($compile) {
       ...
       this.$compile = $compile;
       ...
   }

   ...
 }

 MyController.$inject = ['$compile'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the a solution within the MyDirective class:

```
class MyDirective {
 constructor() {
    this.restrict = 'A';
    this.scope = {};
    this.controllerAs = 'vm';
 }

 controller($compile){
   this.$compile = $compile;
 }

 link(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
    let div = angular.element(document.getElementById('targetDiv'));

    let compiled = ctrl.$compile("<another-directive></another-directive>")(scope));
 }
}

MyDirective.$inject = ['$compile'];
```